# Why was Ebisu killed by the Pacification Ring?

Tags: noragami

During the incantation, the lines spoken by the Gods are:

[image]

We know that Ebisu did have a "pure heart". As the [Wikia article on Ebisu](http://noragami.wikia.com/wiki/Ebisu) states:

> **He is also a truly kind God, as his desire to control and name Ayakashi and go to the underworld to retrieve the locution brush is because he believed if he did so he could relieve some of the strife and pain that Ayakashi cause and make the world a truly better place.** This is shown when he is reincarnated and talks to Yato, saying when he realized he existed he took in the atmosphere and immediately fell in love with the world and wanted to bring the world and humans happiness, with Yato stating that was his true inner character and the type of person he has always been and will be. This is once again stated in chapter 39 by Kunimi, who states that the master wanted to control Ayakashi to improve the world as he grew to understand that money alone cannot make humans happy.

---

I doubt that the lines spoken during the incantation don't hold any meaning because they make perfect sense.

Is there any logical basis for his death being caused by the Pacification Ring?

Comment: I'd like to mention that in the manga, Ebisu is simply killed in a battle against another god, while Bishamon tried to protect him.

Comment: I think it's because he use that brush. Controlling Ayakashi is a sin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have two theories to why Ebisu was killed by the Pacification Ring.

First is that the Ring is just a energy cannon that is meant to exterminate the enemies of heaven. Therefore, it not only affects Ebisu but also those around him. Quoting from the wikia,

> Pacification Ring, a form of punishment to destroy enemies of Heaven.
>   [image: Kofuku]
>   [image: Daikoku]
>   [image: Ebisu]

Second, he was not 'pure of heart'. We can take the words the other gods said to mean 'pure' by their standards and not Ebisu nor our standards. Therefore, Ebisu, who has committed sins against heaven, is not 'pure' of heart, according to the other gods, who cast the ring. This god here said that what Ebisu did are taboos and we can infer that by the standard of the other gods, Ebisu is not 'pure' of heart anymore.

[image]

> As Sigfried666 also mentioned, in the manga, Ebisu is killed by [Takemikazuchi](http://noragami.wikia.com/wiki/Takemikazuchi)'s [Kiun](http://noragami.wikia.com/wiki/Kiun). Therefore, the ring is an anime only event and may not have any logical justification.

Comment: Good theories. Since there's no canonical justification for the question yet, I'm accepting this answer.

Answer (score 0):

After looking over the wording of the scene where he was killed, I believe that those lines were true. It would miss if he'd have been pure of heart. They DID miss. At least, when the lines were said while firing. Someone willing to risk their life jumped in front of him and destroyed the shot, which in a way solidified the fact that he was pure of heart, that someone who barely knew him was willing to risk their life for his sake. The second shot would have likely killed anyone, regardless of whether they were "pure of heart" or not.

Answer (score -2):

Those lines have no meaning, the gods were just so sure of Ebisu's sins that they didn't expect the next shot to miss.